# Overriding the delete function of BaseInlineFormset

Tags: django, django-forms

I am looking at doing a soft delete on a record. If 'Website' is not a foreign key (say, for example 'RetailerRatingGroup') then it should be deleted as normal. However, it is the foreign key of another object, I want to cancel the deletion and instead change the Website.active property to false. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I might go about that.

```
class Website(models.Model):
    retailer = models.ForeignKey('Retailer', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    url = models.URLField()
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class RetailerRatingGroup(models.Model):
    retailer = models.ForeignKey(Retailer, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    channel_productcat = models.ForeignKey('ChannelProductcatGroup', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    website = models.ForeignKey(Website, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    current_rating = models.ForeignKey('Rating', default=None, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK ... so after even more looking around I found the following:

```
class SoftDeleteInlineFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def delete_existing(self, obj, commit=True):
        if commit:
            if not obj.retailerratinggroup_set.all().exists():
                obj.delete()
            else:
                obj.active = False
                obj.save()

WebsiteFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Retailer, Website, form=WebsiteForm, formset=SoftDeleteInlineFormset, max_num=10, extra=3, can_delete=True)
```

Ideally it would be better to see if any model had was using the website instance as a foreign key.